# How to addClass to the first td in every tr inside a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-table

I'm trying to add a class to the first td inside a tr within a specific class.  But for some reason it adds this class only to the first td in the first tr -not the first td in each tr

```
$("#appendTD").find("#gridFormInformation").children(0).children().each(
                function() {
                    if ($("#appendTD").find('tr').filter(function() { return $(this).attr('class') == 'ui-widget-content ui-subtblcell'; }).children("td:eq(0)").addClass("leftbord"));
                }
            );
```

But when I alter the above by removing the ""td:eq(0)" it adds this class to each td in each tr ... so what am I doing wrong?

Example of the markup below

```
<td id="appendTD">
  <table id="gridFormInformation">
    <tbody>
      <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th></tr>
      <tr class="ui-widget-content ui-subtblcell"><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr class="ui-widget-content ui-subtblcell"><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr class="ui-widget-content ui-subtblcell"><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you're using a complicated manual way to find the tds you want to add the class to. I believe it would be easier to use jQuery selectors to find your tds.

Replace

```
$("#appendTD").find("#gridFormInformation").children(0).children().each(
            function() {
                if ($("#appendTD").find('tr').filter(function() { return $(this).attr('class') == 'ui-widget-content ui-subtblcell'; }).children("td:eq(0)").addClass("leftbord"));
            }
        );
```

with

```
$("#gridFormInformation tr.ui-widget-content.ui-subtblcell").find("td:first").addClass("leftbord");
```

This would find all the trs and for each tr find the first td and add the class to that.

Answer (score 2):

Change `'td:eq(0)` to `'td:first'`.

Answer (score 2):

This method is to add `leftbord` to the first `<td>` in each row of the table `gridFormInformation`:

```
$('#gridFormInformation tr td:first-child').addClass('leftbord');
```